# Overflowing text on jquery buttons on mobile Safari

Tags: jquery, iphone, mobile-safari, accessibility

I have a jquery web app which looks great on my iPhone. I just had a look at it on someone else's iPhone and they have **bold text** turned on in accessibility. The problem with this is that much of the text on buttons overflows. For example, rather than "Confirm" on a button, their phone shows "Co...", which is a bit useless. This is a company internal web app, so it only needs to run on iPhones.

Any ideas how to address this?

Comment: Remove the `overflow:hidden` or equivalent from buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using relative units (em, rem) in your css element sizing can help prevent this from happening. Also avoid using set widths on your elements as overflowing text might be cut off.

The WCAG AA criteria states that the user must be able to resize their text up to 200 percent without loss of content or functionality, so it's important to ensure that any buttons will grow as the text increases. You can eliminate any set widths that might be on the buttons, otherwise they should expand relative to the text inside them.

source on the wcag criteria: https://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/visual-audio-contrast-scale.html

Comment: Thanks for this @Skerrvy. That's great advice but I'm not sure how to implement that since I'm using jQuery as the library to render all of that text. Could you point me in the right direction? Cheers

Comment: this fiddle is illustrating the second point (how setting the height/width will cut off text when the font size is increased: https://jsfiddle.net/ym1nb48u/3/ .


this second link illustrates the first point (using relative units) to size things so when the page is magnified, the elements all scale at the same rate: https://jsfiddle.net/ym1nb48u/4/